# JsonSlurper().parseText multiline strings from a file

Tags: json, groovy

How to parse a a file as multiline strings?

I am trying to escape the double quotes within my jsonfile so I have used the multiline strings but can't figure out how to pass the jsonfile as multiline strings.

I have a code like this:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import groovy.json.JsonOutput

def script = new File('${jsonfile}')

if (!script || !script.exists()) {
    println "Script file '${jsonfile}' doesn't exist"
    System.exit(1)
}

File scriptContent = new File ("${script}")

def content = new JsonSlurper().parseText '''
scriptContent.text
'''
```

jsonfile:

```
{
  "admin_id": "admin_user",
  "admin_pwd": "admin_password",
  "commands": [
"command one",
"command two",
"command \\\"three\\\" with double quotes",
"command four",
  ]
}
```

Comment: If the name of your file is `jsonfile` then this should work: `new JsonSlurper().parse( new File('jsonfile') )`

Comment: Isn't `"command \"three\" with double quotes"` enough for escaping quotes?

Comment: I found out that the issue is not within the JsonSlurper.  It was the next line which is ```def text = JsonOutput.toJson(content)```
the escape character \ is returning back.